# How to get data from API (JSON) in android?

Tags: android, json, api, parsing

I tried to get some data from song API. What I want to get is the tags from the song.

Here the JSON :

```
{"track":
    {"name":"Let It Happen",
    "url":"http://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala/_/Let+It+Happen",
    "duration":"469000",
    "streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},
    "listeners":"150111",
    "playcount":"758518",
    "artist":{"name":"Tame Impala","mbid":"63aa26c3-d59b-4da4-84ac-716b54f1ef4d","url":"http://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala"},
    "toptags":
        {"tag":[
            {"name":"indie","url":"http://www.last.fm/tag/indie"},
            {"name":"psychedelic","url":"http://www.last.fm/tag/psychedelic"},
            {"name":"Psychedelic Rock","url":"http://www.last.fm/tag/Psychedelic+Rock"},
            {"name":"2015","url":"http://www.last.fm/tag/2015"},
            {"name":"electronic","url":"http://www.last.fm/tag/electronic"}
            ]
        },
    "wiki":
        {"published":"11 Mar 2015, 08:59","summary":"Let It Happen is the opening track and first song revealed from Tame Impala's upcoming third album, Currents. <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala/_/Let+It+Happen\">Read more on Last.fm</a>.","content":"Let It Happen is the opening track and first song revealed from Tame Impala's upcoming third album, Currents. <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/Tame+Impala/_/Let+It+Happen\">Read more on Last.fm</a>. User-contributed text is available under the Creative Commons By-SA License; additional terms may apply."}
    }
}
```

From what I've learned, I use this code to parse it

```
private static ArrayList<String> parseTagsAPI(final String response)
{
    ArrayList<String> tagTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        String tag="", logtag="test, test2";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        if (jsonObject.has("track"))
        {
            JSONObject jsonTrack = jsonObject.getJSONObject("track");
            Log.d("API (tag)", "track");

            if (jsonObject.has("toptags"))
            {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonTrack.getJSONObject("toptags").getJSONArray("tag");
                Log.d("API (tag)", "track > album > toptags > tag(array)");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("name"))
                    {
                        JSONObject tagArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("name");
                        tag = tagArray.optString("name");

                        logtag += (tag + ", ");
                        Log.d("API (tag)", "tags : " + tag);
                    }
                    tagTemp.add(tag);
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("API (tag)", "Logtag : "+logtag);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return tagTemp;
}
```

I put some logs to mark the progress, but it only show 2 logs:

- Log.d("API (tag)", "track");
- Log.d("API (tag)", "Logtag :"+logtag); -> this var is empty

which means my second `if` doesnt work. Anyone know why this is happen?

Comment: post the full json response

Comment: json is not complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong here:

```
JSONObject tagArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("name");
tag = tagArray.optString("name");
```

you should do instead:

```
tag = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
```

or

```
tag = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("name");
```

Also change this:

```
if (jsonObject.has("toptags"))
```

to

```
if (jsonTrack.has("toptags"))
```

Comment: thanks sir. It was my bad, just search it for hours and got desperate XD much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
You're looking for the wrong tag - it's just a typo. 

    private static ArrayList<String> parseTagsAPI(final String response)
{   ArrayList<String> tagTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {   String tag="", logtag="test, test2";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        if (jsonObject.has("track"))
        {   JSONObject jsonTrack = jsonObject.getJSONObject("track");
            Log.d("API (tag)", "track");

            if (jsonObject.has("toptags"))
            {   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonTrack.getJSONObject("toptags").getJSONArray("tag");
                Log.d("API (tag)", "track > album > toptags > tag(array)");
```

Notice that you're looking for `jsonObject.has("toptags")` rather than `jsonTrack.has("toptags");`

Comment: thank you sir, it was foolish T.T i've search it for hours and got desperate haha. Thanks!!